# Select at least one Radio / Checkbox within a active tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radiobuttonlist

I'm using a Bootstrap tab to display the Survey Question and Answers (either Checkbox list or Radio button list). I need to validate that in each tab (if it is Active at that moment ) at least one Radio / Checkbox should be selected. How can I achieve this?

My DOM looks like this

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tab" class="tab-pane active" id="1">
        <div class="considerable">
           ... Radio button list goes here 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tab" class="tab-pane" id="2">
        <div class="considerable">
           ... Checkbox list goes here 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divCalculatorControl">
    <a href="#" id="aSwitchToBack" style="">Back</a>
    <a href="#" id="aSwitchToNext">Next</a>
</div>
```

On click of anchor with id "aSwitchToNext" I need to validate the input selection.

I tried as below, but it's working for non-active tabs also.

```
if ($('div.active > .considerable > input:checked').length) {
   // Continue
}
else{
   alert("Please select an answer");
}
```

Comment: try if hasClass("active")

Comment: @clearshot66 first I need to get is it active tab or not (bootstrap) then within that I need to check if anything selected or not.

Comment: Supply your full html please

Answer (score 0):

Use has class on click of back or next, then check the number of radio buttons and checkboxes under that div that are checked or not

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#aSwitchToBack").click(function(){
         if($(".tab-pane").hasClass("active")){
                var err = 0;
            if($(this).find("input:radio:checked").length < 1){
                err++;
            }
            if($(this).find("input:checkbox:checked").length < 1){
                err++;
            }
            if(err > 1){
                 // stop here
            }
         }
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Check Demo **[here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/mLqKvm?editors=0011)**

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("show.bs.tab", function(e) {
    let getCurrenActiveTabContent = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href");
    let activePanel = getCurrenActiveTabContent + " input";
    if (!$(activePanel).is(":checked")) {
      return false;
    }    
  });
});
```